# JList's TransferHandler.createTransferable() and .exportDone() not called

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jlist

I've added a custom `TransferHandler` to my `JList` in order to override some functionality.

Specifically, I wanted to set custom DataFlavor so as to disable dragging into ComboBox and text fields.

```
fileList.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler() {

        @Override
        public int getSourceActions(JComponent comp) {
            return COPY;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {
            // this works
        }

        @Override
        public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) {
            // this works too
        }

        @Override
        protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {

            // WONT WORK
            System.out.println("export done");
        }

        @Override
        protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {               

            // NEITHER THIS
            System.out.println("createTransferable");

            return new Transferable() {
                // some stuff
            };
        }
    });
```

Anyone got any ideas why `exportDone` and `createTransferable` don't get called?

Comment: And I'd like the downvoter to tell me what is the hate for.

Comment: Four years later, this actually helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Transfer handler needs to be in its own class and set on each the source and target components.
The source component will call the createTransferable() method

```
CustomTransferHandler customTransferHandler = new CustomTransferHandler();

sourceComponent.setTransferHandler(customTransferHandler);
targetComponent.setTransferHandler(customerTransferHandler);
```

Comment: lol this question is a YEAR old :D
I no longer even know in what project I needed it..

Comment: lol I thought it would be useful as a reference for others. Looking at quick examples, this is not super apparent. Mind accepting the answer since it is correct?

Comment: Definitely is. I had the problem this morning and resolved it with that ;-)  Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I remember i had such an issue with a JTabbedPane.
Check API for setDropEnabled or sth like this. I write from my phone so i can't say exactly.

Also make sure your JList fire a drag started event.